# Amazon Alexa skill endpoint not reachable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I defined a skill model using Interaction Model Builder Beta on Amazon developer console.
I have also defined a simple lambda function using AWS Lambda;

```
'use strict';

console.log('Loading function');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));    
    callback(null, "Hello world");
};
```

In the testing part I enter a utterance, I can see a JSON request being created but the response is :

> *The remote endpoint could not be called, or the response it returned was invalid.*

I took the request JSON and created a test for my function in AWS Lambda. The test passes successfully and returns "hello world" for the request.

The trigger for my function is "Alexa Skills Kit".
The function logs arent showing anything.

Any idea why it doesnt work?
Is there some sort of authentication issue? Do I need to flick a switch somewhere?

The ARN address I use looks like this is *arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:481045208193:function:eventCount*.

Answer (score 1):

Your Lambda `handler` needs to have a dependency to the `alexa-sdk`.

For example

```
import Alexa from 'alexa-sdk';

export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const alexaHandler = Alexa.handler(event, context, callback);
    alexaHandler.appId = 'amzn1.ask.skill.XXX';
    alexaHandler.registerHandlers(
        // DEFINE YOUR HANDLERS HERE
    );
    alexaHandler.execute();
};
```

For more informations and examples take a look here: [Alexa Skills Kit SDK for Node.js](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think this answers my initial question ( for some reason cant mark it as an answer on my phone, so will do it later ). I have downloaded the whole github package and tried uploading the zip file just to see if the included index.js will compile, but I get "errorMessage": "Cannot find module 'alexa-sdk'". I see that the internet is suggesting I need to upload the sdk package, but isn't that I just did ? Clearly you have some experience, any advice on this particular issue ?

Comment: Did you run `npm install` to install all the dependencies?

Comment: After digging round I manged to get to this: If I use the stock index.js file `var AlexaLambdaHandler = require('./lib/alexa');
module.exports.handler = AlexaLambdaHandler.LambdaHandler;
module.exports.CreateStateHandler = AlexaLambdaHandler.CreateStateHandler;
module.exports.StateString = AlexaLambdaHandler.StateString;` execute test from Alexa testing page I get "Invalid response".

Comment: When I add `exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));    
    callback(null, "Hello world");
};` I get the error defined initially. In both cases the test on AWS Lambda pages pass

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create node.js skills without using the Alexa SDK.
[this is the link to a github gist](https://gist.github.com/xubidor/daa46bb0ea55d425df07fef52e38709f) for a live skill called "counting cards" that does not use the SDK.

From my experience the Service Simulator in the Alexa Developer Console is full of bugs.  If your function works on Lambda after copying in the JSON created by the Service Simulator then the "arn" is probably ok.
Have you tried invoking your skill using an actual Amazon Alexa or Amazon Echo? You may be surprised to find that your skill actually works.

Your arn is fine as the Alexa Skill Kit is supported in US-N.Virginia and EU-Ireland.